# jQuery Tooltip only works for first row of table

Tags: jquery, tooltip

The jQuery tooltip works great for the first row of data in my table. After that, I only get the old school windows default tooltip in both IE and FF.

Here is the HTML that builds table data:

```
foreach ($displayData as $row) {
echo '<tr bgcolor="' . $bgcolor[$a] . '">';
    echo '<td><span id="fancy" title="Course Description: - '.$row["TSTRDS"].'">'.$row["TSTRTP"].'</span></td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row["TSTRLC"].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row["TSADDR"].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row["TSDATE"].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row["TSTIME"].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row["TSCOST"].'</td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '<tr bgcolor="' . $bgcolor[$a] . '">';
    echo '<td colspan="2"></td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row["TSCITY"].','.$row["TSST"].' '.$row["TSZIP"].'</td>';
    echo '<td colspan="3"></td>';
echo '</tr>';
$a = !$a;
```

}

Here is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#fancy').tooltip({
    track: true,
    delay: 0,
    showURL: false,
    fixPNG: true,
    showBody: " - ",
    top: -15,
    left: 5
});
```

});

And lastly, my CSS:

```
#tooltip {
position: absolute;
border: 1px solid #111;
background-color: #eee;
padding: 5px;
font-size: 14px;
width: 400px; }
```

Seems odd that the first row works and the rest do not. Do I need some sort of looping javascript to use the tooltip for all rows of my table? I thought that jQuery tooltip would take care of that sort of thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of an ID like this:

```
id="fancy"
```

You should use a class like this:

```
class="fancy"
```

then bind it using a [`.class` selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/), like this:

```
$('.fancy').tooltip({
```

IDs are supposed to be unique in a document...when you break this rule, things start to get scary :)  Use a class in situations like this one.

Comment: @deaddancer - Welcome :)  and welcome to SO!, be sure to accept answers that resolve your problems via the check-mark beside the one that helped most on the questions you ask :)