# Mouseover problems and jquery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with jquery effects on few blocks.
Mouseenter and mouseleave work only on the first div block while on all others it doesn't.

Here is the JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

     $('#mainbox').mouseenter(
         function () {
           $('#infobox').fadeIn();
         }); 
     $('#mainbox').mouseleave(
         function () {
           $('#infobox').fadeOut();
         });

   });
```

And also blocks:

```
<div id="mainbox"><div id="infobox" style="display: none;">first block - it works on      this one</div></div>

<div id="mainbox"><div id="infobox" style="display: none;">2nd block - it doesn't work/div></div>

<div id="mainbox"><div id="infobox" style="display: none;">3rd block - it doesn't work</div></div>
```

Do you guys have any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: **IDs must be unique!**

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same ID. ID needs to be unique per the document.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Tooltip only works for first row of table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497930/jquery-tooltip-only-works-for-first-row-of-table)

Comment: To be more exact, you CAN have multiple IDs in one document, however it's not standard compliant. A selector like `$('#mainbox')` will only return the first found though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change id to class:

```
<div class="mainbox"><div class="infobox" style="display: none;">first block - it works on      this one</div></div>


<div class="mainbox"><div class="infobox" style="display: none;">2nd block - it doesn't work/div></div>

<div class="mainbox"><div class="infobox" style="display: none;">3rd block - it doesn't work</div></div>
```

Then in JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('.mainbox').mouseenter(
     function () {
       $(this).find('.infobox').fadeIn();
     }); 
 $('.mainbox').mouseleave(
     function () {
       $(this).find('.infobox').fadeOut();
     });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is: That selector targets only the first infobox inside the first mainbox in your document.

In the [API](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) you can read:

> Each id value must be used only once within a document. If more than
>   one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID
>   will only select the first matched element in the DOM. This behavior
>   should not be relied on, however; a document with more than one
>   element using the same ID is invalid.

And that, is why your code isn't working.

Hint:
Switch ids to classes and bind the mouse events to search inside the div like:

```
$('.mainbox').mouseenter(
  function () {
    $(this).find('.infobox').fadeIn();
  }); 

$('.mainbox').mouseleave(
  function () {
    $(this).find('.infobox').fadeOut();
});
```